# Rails: wkhtmltopdf RuntimeError (Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 to develop an app in Ruby on Rails.
In the app I need to generate pdf documents. So I am using
the wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary gems.

In the development environment in my system everything is working fine.
But once I deployed the app in production on CentOS 5.6 using Phusion 
Passenger, when I try to generate pdfs on the fly its giving me the following error:

**RuntimeError (Location of wkhtmltopdf unknown)**

I am using Ruby1.9.2.p136
           Rails 3.1.1

Any help will be much appreciated....Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

do you use static wkhtmltopdf binary? i downloaded it [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list) and extraced it to `/path/to/rails_app/bin`

and add it to rails like this:

```
#config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386').to_s,
}
```

Comment: Changed from i386 to amd64 and this worked for Heroku as well.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative is to install the binary via the Gemfile.

Just add the following line to your production group:

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

That should add binary support for linux-i386, amd64, and darwin.

And then run

```
bundle install --without development test
```

to install the gem in a production environment. After which, you just restart your server.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 8):

for mac os - x you should install wkhtmltopdf by homebrew

```
$ brew tap homebrew/boneyard # the wkhtmltopdf formula is now inactive but still available in the boneyard repository 
$ brew install wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: It's not available anymore: `Error: No available formula for wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: try again but first install boneyard: $ brew tap homebrew/boneyard 

the brew formular wkhtmltopdf is inactive but still available under the boneyard repo

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for OS X Yosemite**

To get it working on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), install the `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem and then put it in your `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`:

```
module WickedPdfHelper
  if Rails.env.development?
    if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /linux/
      executable = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu'] == 'x86_64' ? 'wkhtmltopdf_linux_x64' : 'wkhtmltopdf_linux_386'
    elsif RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /darwin/
      executable = 'wkhtmltopdf_darwin_386'
    else
      raise 'Invalid platform. Must be running linux or intel-based Mac OS.'
    end

    WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: "#{Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary').match(/(.+)\/.+/).captures.first}/#{executable}" }
  end
end
```

Ps.: This solution will work on Linux too.

Comment: Great! This worked for me. Do you any idea why this is now needed?

Comment: @nathanvda I have no idea. But I'd like to know as well.

Comment: For mac osx, same way that @ben noticed, just you should set path where your binary file is placed, and also put right name, for example: Rails.root.join('/usr/local/bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s,

Answer (score 1):

**MAC OSX:**

```
brew install wkhtmltopdf
```

this will let you to install

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf
```

then in `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb`

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem.

As stated in [readme](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), I created an initializer with:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```