# Rails wkhtmltopdf not working on Yosemite MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I upgraded my MAC to Yosemite and now wkhtmltopdf isn't working in a Rails app.  The browser times out with "No Data Received".

I'm using PDFkit - it has

```
config.wktmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin','wkhtmltopdf').to_s if Rails.env.development?
```

I have 2 files in bin:

```
wkhtmltopdf
wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

I tried adding this:

gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

I get the same results

I'm not getting any errors in the Rails log.  The browser shows this "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE "

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE 1

I tried: `brew install wkhtmltopdf` - but first, I had to re-install Brew.

Get the same results.

Comment: What error do you have in the rails logfile? I think I am having the same issue.

Comment: BTW: I you are having the same issue, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26581219/216513) solved my problem. Good luck!

Comment: nathanvda - are you using Wickedpdf?  I'm using PDFkit.  Did you use the selected answer from the referred stack overflow issue?

Comment: Ow sorry, I am indeed using `WickedPDF` and `wkhtmltopdf-binary`, I used the answer I linked to (not the selected answer): so adding an initializer to correctly find the executable. So probably not applicable. In my logfile I got the error a file could not be found :)